# Change the limit from CakePHP 3 Paginator by click in link inside an <option>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, cakephp

I'm using the CakePHP 3.0 to paginate some content, but I can't find a way to change the limit (user on browser choose the limit of content displayed on screen) using `Paginator` built-in method (like sort built-in), to do this I use javascript to change limit in URL.

**Qustion:** Exist any way to do this in cakephp style ?

**Controller action that uses paginate**

```
public $helpers = [
    'Paginator' => ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']
];

public function search()
{
    if($this->request->is('get'))
    {
        $search = $this->request->query['search'];
        @$limit = $this->request->query['limit'] ?: 3;

        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => ['product_name LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%'],
            'limit' => $limit,
            'contain' => ['Medias' => function($q){
                return $q->select(['path', 'product_id'])
                    ->where(['media_type_id' => 3]);
            }]
        ];

        $products = $this->paginate($this->Products);
     }
}
```

**Select with pagination limits:**

```
<select name="products-view" class="form-control products-view inline-pagination-menu" id="products-view">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript responsible to change `limit` in URL**

```
$('#products-view').change(function(){
    changeLimitPagination(this);
});

function changeLimitPagination(option){
    location.search = $.query.set('limit', option.value).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will admit that I am not really familiar with CakePHP so I am not sure how to answer "*Exist any way to do this in cakephp style?*" - did you ever find an answer for that?

I am intrigued by the following line:

> ```
> @$limit = $this->request->query['limit'] ?: 3;
> ```

shouldn't the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) be prepended before the right hand side of the assignment operator?

```
$limit = @$this->request->query['limit'] ?: 3;
```

I haven't tried the error control operator on that side... maybe it still works the same...

---

Looking at the JavaScript code, it appears that the `option` parameter actually corresponds to the select list

```js
$('#products-view').change(function(){
    changeLimitPagination(this);
});

function changeLimitPagination(option){
    console.log(' option tagName: ', option.tagName, ' id: ', option.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="products-view" class="form-control products-view inline-pagination-menu" id="products-view">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

So a better name would be something like `productsList` or `limitList`. Also, that doesn't really need to be a parameter - it could be stored in a variable outside the function. While you might still need to use jQuery for other code, regular JavaScript code could be used to select the element by *id* attribute with [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and then add the change handler via [`EventTarget.addEventHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). That way, `changeLimitPagination` could simply be added as the callback to the change handler instead of an extra anonymous function that has the sole purpose of calling `changeLimitPagination`.

```js
var productsView = document.getElementById('products-view');
productsView.addEventListener('change', changeLimitPagination);

function changeLimitPagination(){
    console.log('changeLimitPagintation() - value: ', productsView.value);
    //location.search = $.query.set('limit', option.value).toString();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="products-view" class="form-control products-view inline-pagination-menu" id="products-view">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```